# Scheduled Windows Task jar

Tags: java, windows, task

i try to start a java application with a scheduled windows task. I have 3 other java programs, which are running fine. 
What i've tried:

1) Start Program: "C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\java.exe" Arguments: -jar C:\pathtomyprogramm\myprogram.jar. I also tried javaw.exe cuase that application has GUI. I filled the start in field, but i didn't work.

2) I then wrote a batch file, which starts the application. When i run the batch file manually everything works fine. Starting it with the scheduled task doesn't work.

There is no error message, the scheduler just exectues the task, but nothing happens. No new process in the taskmanager, nothing.

Maybe someone can help me out, maybe i'm just blind and can't see something obvious :)

Cheers Mike

Comment: Can you please attach a Screenshot, showing how you configured the "Windows Task Schedular"?

Comment: Does pathtomyprogramm contain /Program Files/ or /Program Files (x86)/ ?

Comment: No the path is C:\logging\myjar.jar without spaces. Which part of the taskconfig should be on the scrrenshot ?